# How do I use the "File Editing" permission in a browser?

Tags: javascript, web, scripting, chromium

How can I create a website that asks if it can use the file editing permission to get a specific file and do file processing?

I'm also wondering if the same thing can be done with other permissions.

I tried to research the topic but I don't know alot about javascript or website development.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create an HTML file and set up the basic structure with the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags.

Inside the `<body>` tag, add a button that users can click to select the file they want to process. You can use the `<input>` tag with the `type="file"` attribute to create a file input field.

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
<button onclick="processFile()">Process File</button>
```

Create a `<script>` tag inside the `<body>` tag or in the `<head>` tag to write your JavaScript code.
In your JavaScript code, you can use the File API to access and process files. Before you can access the file, you need to request permission from the user using the navigator.permissions API.

```
sync function processFile() {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  const file = fileInput.files[0];

  // Request permission to edit the file
  const permission = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'file-system' });
  if (permission.state === 'granted') {
    // Perform file processing here
    console.log('File editing permission granted');
    // Your file processing code goes here
  } else {
    console.log('File editing permission denied');
  }
}
```

Once you have obtained the file and the necessary permission, you can perform the desired file processing operations using JavaScript.

```
function processFile() {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  const file = fileInput.files[0];

  // Perform file processing here
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    const fileContent = e.target.result;
    console.log('File content:', fileContent);
    // Your file processing code goes here
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```